# Is <iframe> the only way to implement external apps for WebOS?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, messaging, web-worker

I'm working on project, where we're trying to implement something similar to the WebOS. Several people are providing the idea to load external applications using the `<iframe>`.

I've search and found: https://osjsv2.0o.no/ , this project also uses  (you many inspect DOM in demo to see it).

But, as for me, I found this idea rather bad, because as I understand  is secure only when cross domain is forbidden (`parent.document` won't be accessed).

If there is some kind of JavaScript API, which is accessible in parent document, but it's inaccessible due disallowed cross-domain option for `<iframe>` - you won't be able to use some kind of this JS API.

Won't be the way of virtualizing the parent DOM (encapsulating) and messaging via `Web-Workers` with using the structured clone algorithm more clever and safe way?

Also, it's necessary to mention about security. If cross-domain communication is allowed between `<iframe>` and parent document - there is a possible issue, that attacker could load JSON in `<iframe>` app, which will break parent DOM or make some spy-stuff for inputs or other...

So, the main question is: **Is the `<iframe>` secure and the only way to load external apps in Web OS (like the `OS.js`) in 2016 (soon 2017) year?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a WebOS user, but if it provides access, `fetch()` and `ServiceWorker` scripts allow you to break out of the CORS restrictions. You would need to evaluate the script in some sandbox afterwards, like [`jailed`](https://github.com/asvd/jailed), where you can construct the context for the code running within.